# Python_ Taking multiple inputs of different data type in one line

Tags: python

I wish to take in two inputs from the user in one line, a score (in integer) and a name (in string) in one line, separated by a blank space.

So for example, an input may be `90 Amy`.

I don't want to store both as string and then convert one later; I want to store one as an integer and one as a string from the start.

I have tried some codes but they are not working and I'm struggling.

```
score, name = (int(input()), input()).split()

print(score)
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is one line solution, but not efficient:

```
x, y = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in input("Enter two value: ").split()]
```

Convert input to array and check if all elements digit or not. This is how it works.

Try this if you have no problem with 2 line:

```
x, y = input("Enter a two value: ").split()
x = int(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to read only one line from the console (ie one `input`) you may not to try non-intuitive thing, just use two lines and do

  ```
  result = input().split()
  score, name = int(result[0]), result[1]
  ```
- If you're ok to read 2 lines, (ie 2 `input`)

  ```
  score, name = int(input('Score: ')), input('Name: ')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
score, name = int(input('Enter Score: ')), input('Enter name:')

print(score)
print(name)
```